# comparing elements of a list from an *args

Tags: python-3.x

I have this function that I need to compare the strings in a list to a `*args`
The reason being is that, the user should be able to type any words in the 2nd argument. However when I try to compare the strings to the `*args` it doesn't give me any results

```
def title_case2(title, *minor_words):
    for x in title.split():
        if x in minor_words:
            print(x)
```

Assuming I ran the function with the parameters below. I was hoping it would display **a** and **of** since these words are found on those 2 entries.

```
title_case2('a clash of KINGS','a an the of')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
def title_case2(title, *minor_words):
    minor_words = [j for i in minor_words for j in i.split()]  #Create a flat list. 
    for x in title.split():
        if x in minor_words:
            print(x)
title_case2('a clash of KINGS','a an the of', "Jam")
```

---

using a `for-loop` instead of list comprehension

```
def title_case2(title, *minor_words):
    minor_words_r = []
    for i in minor_words:
        for j in i.split():
            minor_words_r.append(j)
    for x in title.split():
        if x in minor_words_r:
            print(x)
```

Comment: im not yet good at list comprehension can you explain this a bit further. If I am going to use the for loop:

lst = []

for i in minor words:
     for j in i.split():
          lst.append(j)

Comment: Added a `for-loop` approach

Comment: thanks for this so basically the *args gets converted to a list and from there we can manipulate it just like any other regular list.

Answer (score 0):

`*args` is a tuple of arguments, so you're actually checking if `x` is in `('a an the of',)`. So either pass your argument as:

```
title_case2('a clash of KINGS', *'a an the of'.split())
```

Or, use this as your test:

```
if any(x in y for y in minor_words):
```

In either of the above cases the output is:

```
a
of
```